# Compare $E[|X| \cdot 1\{|X| < M\}]$ and $P(|X| < M)$ with $E|X|=1$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, random-variables, expected-value

$X$ is a random variable and $E|X|=1$. Do we know any relation between $P(|X|\leq M)$ and $E[|X| \cdot 1\{|X| \leq M \}]$? Do we only have one direction, i.e., either $P(|X|\leq M) \geq E[|X| \cdot 1\{|X| \leq M \}]$ or $P(|X|\leq M) \leq E[|X| \cdot 1\{|X| \leq M \}$? Or in fact, both cases can happen? EDIT: Especially when $M \to \infty$, what would be the asymptotic comparison?

Comment: For every nonnegative $M$, the function $u:t\mapsto t$ is nondecreasing  on $t\geqslant0$ and the function $v:t\mapsto\mathbf 1_{t\leqslant M}$ is nonincreasing on $t\geqslant0$, hence, by a rearrangement inequality, $$E(u(|X|)v(|X|))\leqslant E(u(|X|))E(v(|X|))$$ If, in addition, $E|X|=1$, this yields $$E(|X|\mathbf 1_{|X|\leqslant M})\leqslant P(|X|\leqslant M)$$

Comment: @Did Thank you. I found that one can also use Chebyshev's association inequality to prove this.

Comment: You could show how, for example by posting an answer below.

Comment: @Did Just post. Thanks for reminding me of the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

(Chebyshev's Association Inequality) $f$ is nonincreasing and $g$ is nondecreasing. $X$ is a real-valued random variable and $Y$ is a nonnegative random variable. Then
$$ E[Y] E[Yf(X)g(X)] \leq E[Yf(X)] E[Yg(X)] .$$
Take $Y \equiv 1$, $f(\cdot) = 1\{|X|\leq \cdot\}$ and $g(\cdot) = |\cdot|$. The result would be similar to Did's comment.